# How to use a context manager in python

Tags: python, with-statement, contextmanager

Below is a hypothetical piece of code

```
with dbengine.connect(**details) as db:
    cur = db.exec(sql_string)
    results = cur.fetchall()
return results
```

In this case I would expect that when tabbed **out** of that with block db.close() is called and db is marked for garbage collection.

In work I've started seeing this code crop up.

```
with something() as myobj:
    logger.info('I got an obj!')
return myobj
```

I don't know if you should be using **with** like the **new** keyword in java. Could someone direct me to any good docs that might explain what you can/can't should/shouldn't do when using with?

P.S Log messages are actually that lame :-)

Comment: The second snippet makes no sense at all. Hit the guy who wrote it. Hit him hard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The target name the `with` statement binds the contextmanager `__enter__` return value *to* (the name after `as`) is not scoped to just the `with` statement. Like `for` loop variable, the `as` target name is scoped in the current function or module namespace. The name does not disappear or is otherwise cleared when the `with` suite ends.

As such, `return myobj` *outside* of the `with` statement is perfectly legal, if somewhat nonsensical. All that the `with` statement guarantees is that the `something().__exit__()` method will have been called when the block completes (be that by reaching the end of the block, or because of a `continue`, `break` or `return` statement, or because an exception has been raised).

That said, you'd be better off just moving the return *inside* the `with` statement:

```
with something() as myobj:
    logger.info('I got an obj!')
    return myobj
```

and

```
with dbengine.connect(**details) as db:
    cur = db.exec(sql_string)
    return cur.fetchall()
```

The context manager will still be cleaned up properly, but now the `return` statement looks like it is a logical part of the `with` block. The execution order is not altered; `something().__exit__()` is called, then the function returns.

As always, the [Python documentation on the `with` syntax](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) is excellent. You could also review the [documentation on context managers](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#context-managers) and the [original proposal, PEP-343](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/).